# Mouse Up event at the end of reactive drag and drop with Rxjs in Angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following, hopefully fairly standard, drag and drop code using Rxjs in Angular 2.

The `blockElement` happens to be an SVG rectangle but I don't think that makes any difference to the question.

I need to set the coordinates of the `blockElement` when it's finally dropped, i.e. when the `mouseup` event fires at the end of the drag. This is so that the user can drop it roughly in the right place and the code lines up its position correctly.

Can I achieve that by reacting to the `takeUntil` by running a function? Or is there some other Rxjs operator I can use to react to `mouseup` by running a function when it happens at the end of the drag?

(I've edited the code for clarity, but the actual code does work, so if there's any errors in what follows it shouldn't be relevant to the question and hopefully you get the idea)

```
const taskMouseDown$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.blockElement.nativeElement, 'mousedown');
const documentMouseUp$ = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mouseup');
const documentMouseMove$ = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');

const taskMouseDrag$ = taskMouseDown$.flatMap((mouseEvent: MouseEvent) => {
  return documentMouseMove$.map((mouseMoveEvent: MouseEvent) => {
    return ({mouseStart: mouseEvent, mouseCurrent: moveMouseEvent});
  }).takeUntil(documentMouseUp$);
});

taskMouseDrag$.subscribe(
  // Make the block element follow the mouse
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can use `do` operator like

```
.takeUntil(documentMouseUp$)
.do(
   () => {}, // next
   () => {}, // error
   () => {   // complete
    alert('mouseup')
   }
 );
```

or

```
declare module "rxjs/Observable" {
    interface Observable<T> {
        finish : typeof finish;
    }
}

function finish<T>(this : Observable<any>, fn: () => void): Observable<T> {
    return this.do(() => {}, () => {}, fn);
}

Observable.prototype.finish = finish;

...
.takeUntil(documentMouseUp$)
.finish(() => this.onMouseUp());
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/3Wp8rPhxuisXGLZ4a84S?p=preview)**

2) Or you can just subscribe to `documentMouseUp$`

```
documentMouseUp$.subscribe(() => console.log('mouseup);
```

Comment: Thanks... it was the `do` operator that I needed. I was reluctant to subscribe to the `mouseup` as I thought that would fire even when I wasn't dragging. Anyway `do` does exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

`takeUntil` terminates the stream when the condition is met and you can pass a handler for this:

```
takeMouseDrag$.subscribe(
  nextHandler, // your move handler
  completeHandler, // this gets triggered when the mouseup triggers the take until
  errorHandler // in case you want to handle errors
}
```

or in you case:

```
takeMouseDrag$.subscribe(
  onDrag,
  onDragEnd
)
```

Comment: AFAIK `subscribe` has the next signature `.subscribe([observer] | [onNext], [onError], [onCompleted])`

Comment: And seems `completeHandler` handler for `takeMouseDrag$` won't be triggered because `takeUntil` is used for inner observable `documentMouseMove$`